# Get only value from Array

Tags: javascript, php

I have this query

```
$sqlID  = oci_parse($connect,"select C_ID   from T_user");  
        oci_execute($sqlID);
```

Put the result into array

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($sqlID, OCI_ASSOC)) {
                    $rows[] = $row; 
                }
```

I need to process the array further, so I send it to javascript:

```
var arr = <?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>;
```

The result from console log are:

```
0: {C_ID: "19990535"}
1: {C_ID: "19990553"}
2: {C_ID: "20000118"}
3: {C_ID: "20030130"}
4: {C_ID: "20050124"}
5: {C_ID: "20050179"}
6: {C_ID: "20090027"}
7: {C_ID: "20110153"}
8: {C_ID: "20120112"}
9: {C_ID: "20140083"}
10: {C_ID: "20170008"}
11: {C_ID: "20190206"}
```

My desired output are:

```
0: "19990535"
1: "19990553"
2: "20000118"
3: "20030130"
4: "20110153"
5: "20120112"
6: "20140083"
7: "20170008"
8: "20190206"
9: "20050179"
10: "20050124"
```

I try with : `var arr = <?php echo json_encode(array_values($rows)); ?>;`
but the result still the same.
How to achieve it?

Comment: In your php code, try `$rows[] = $row['C_ID']; ` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to modify your while loop

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($sqlID, OCI_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = $row['C_ID'];
}
```

Comment: [massive dupe](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+only+value+array+site:stackoverflow.com)